# How to stop foreach loop from printing duplicate data?

Tags: php, csv, foreach

I am trying to generate unique `CSV` files from the csv data that I have using the following loop.

```
 $k =1;
 foreach ($csv_tbl as $_csv) {
        $filename = "Agent_" . $k . ".csv";
        $file_path = "agents/$filename";
        file_put_contents($file_path, $_csv);
        if (file_exists($_csv)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($_csv));
            readfile($_csv);
            die();
        }
        $k++;
    }
```

The first file generated is perfect and only has the data it should have i.e the first `csv` table. The second file has both the first and the second tables this goes on for all my 21 files which means the 21st file will have all the tables.

Visual example of the first two files.

[image: Agent_1.csv]
[image: Agent_2.csv]

How can I prevent duplicates tables from my `csv` file?

Comment: @Masiorama I need seperate files.....

Comment: Mh, ok, then I would try checking every row against the time row, assuming it is unique, and remove the subsequent occurrencies... you could fill a multidimensional array using the csv id as key, and inside time as the key and the rest of the data as value... I'm not that sure about that, though.

Comment: To answer your question we need to know what is `$k` and `$csv_tbl`

Comment: @kulaeff `$csv_tbl` is an array that contains all my `csv` data. `$k` is an int `$k=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your foreach is printing duplicates , it means that your `array $csv_tbl` contains duplicate values, you can remove duplicate values from array using `array_unqiue` But also by looking at the screenshots i can see that the callid is different for every record. do your csv contain duplicates?::

```
 $k =1;
 $csv_tbl = array_unique($csv_tbl);
 foreach ($csv_tbl as $_csv) {
        $filename = "Agent_" . $k . ".csv";
        $file_path = "agents/$filename";
        file_put_contents($file_path, $_csv);
        if (file_exists($_csv)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($_csv));
            readfile($_csv);
            die();
        }
        $k++;
    }
```

Comment: After some further investigation you're definitely right about this array does indeed have duplicates.